# Looking for a high performance alternative to StringBuilder

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory, stringbuilder

I have a very simple piece of code which iterates over a list of Database objects and appends certain property to the StringBuilder. Now the results are sometimes going over 100K so the append operations go over 100K

My problem is there is no way I can shorten the number of iterations as I need the data. But Stringbuilder keeps on taking over heap space. And throws OutOfMemoryException.

Has anyone encountered any such situation and is there a solution to this problem or an alternative to StringBuilder.

It is quite possible that what I am doing might as well be wrong so even though code is quite simple I will post it.

```
StringBuilder endResult = new StringBuilder();
        if (dbObjects != null && !dbObjects.isEmpty()) {
            for (DBObject dBO : dbObjects) {
                endResult.append("Starting to write" + dBO.getOutPut() + "content");
                endResult.append(dBO.getResults);
            }
            output.append("END");
        }
```

Like I said it's quite possible that I will have 100000 results from the DB

Comment: If that's throwing an `OutOfMemoryException`, then you should probably reconsider your design. Remember, you will be returning that string afterwards, and that string will be huge. You should consider using a stream or something.

Comment: 100k results does not sound like a lot to me.  How much heap memory do you allocate for Java?  32 bit or 64 bit JVM?  And how much memory on the system? (EDIT: the command line parameter is -Xmx for max memory, what are you using?)

Comment: @markspace intx CompilerThreadStackSize = 0                                 
uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit  = 0                             
uintx HeapSizePerGCThread = 87241520                      
uintx InitialHeapSize = 268435456                     
uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold = 134217728                     
uintx MaxHeapSize = 4294967296                    
intx ThreadStackSize = 1024                          
intx VMThreadStackSize = 1024                          
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode)

Comment: Instead of building a huge string, write the contents of the database to an output file.  Later, you can read the file and not worry about the intermediate strings.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Well I dont know how I would use stream before I can even get to the whole string, Can I? Can you point me to an example where I can avoid using Builder?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc But there are a few operations that I need to perform on this string before I can write them to a file.

Comment: Can the operations you perform be done within the for loop (i.e. on a particular dBO.getResults) or must they be performed on the entire String?  And what do you do with this huge (altered) string if you were to create it?

Comment: @IanMc Well I need to do a bit of a formatting to the end string. And also I am stuck with iterating because I have to insert "endResult.append("Starting to write" + dBO.getOutPut() + "content");" after every object. As you can see in the Question

Comment: Trying to establish if you can 'flush' each iteration, and not build a massive string.  By that I mean create a String combining "Starting to write ...". and append (dBO.getResults) -> Then perform string alteratiion, then flush it somewhere (to disk, etc).  So you don't need a StringBuilder.

Comment: @IanMc Well it is not a bad idea, but unfortunately its adding more twist to my purpose and current design. Basically the constructed string goes back to database as a byte[] So I dont know how I could leave it mid-way and then append to it later on.

Comment: As the for-each loop keeps all the already processed elements in memory, you could replace the for-each loop with `Iterator<DBObject> iter = dbObjects.iterator(); while(iter.hasNext()) { DBObject dBO = iter.next(); ... iter.remove(); }` This will remove the object from the actual list while the loop is still iterating through the elements and therefore make the removed element eligible for garbage collection, which might lower the memory footprint of your application. Also, instead of loading all 100.000 elements, try to page through the dataset.

Comment: @RomanVottner Paging through the DataSet was the next option that I was going to try. Dunno exactly how well it is going to help but because I have a huge dataset it should release quite a lot of memory for me. Lets see how it turns out.

Comment: Normally byte arrays can be added to by startPos.  In your loop, you keep track of totalBytesWritten, and each new write you write at that position.  I don't know BLOB, but suspect it has a similar feature.

Comment: Well, it depends on what you want to do with the resulting `StringBuilder`? With large amounts of data, it is common to process this data in chunks instead of collecting the whole thing into one big string.

Comment: The irony is that `StringBuilder` exists as the "high performance" alternative to multiple string concatenations (it's a mutable companion class; many compilers internally replace multiple concatenation with a `StringBuilder`).  It would seem to me that if you can't get what you want using `StringBuilder`, then your design issues require a very different approach.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do something like this when using `StringBuilder`:

```
endResult.append("Starting to write" + dBO.getOutPut() + "content");
```

The above statement will do string concatenation. Use the `append()` method like:

```
endResult.append("Starting to write").append(dBO.getOutPut()).append("content");
```

Comment: append.append.append is even more scarier because append internally does an arrayCopy and in my case since the iterations are over 100K each append kills my memory by calling ArrayCopy

Comment: @john.p.doe, concatenation also needs array copy and `append()` better than concatenation... But in your particular case, you should really consider using a `ResultSet` probably and read only what's required instead of creating a huge string...

Comment: @Codebender But I am using only whats needed. The appends that you see do not contain anything that I do not need.

Comment: @Codebender But if I have a endResult.append("Starting to write" + dBO.getOutPut() + "content") wouldn't the arrayCopy happen on smaller portions like "Starting to write" then dBO.getOutPut() and then "content" and one final ArrayCopy on StringBuilder which seems to grow like a monster. So I was thinking why have huge ArrayCopy on StringBuilder 3-4 times. Am I missing something important here or is my concept wrong?

Comment: @john.p.doe, StringBuilder's capacity expands in multiples of 2... So it's not going to copy itself on every append...

Comment: for simple concatenation you don't need to use StringBuilder (append) the compiler will do the trick for you ;) http://www.pellegrino.link/2015/08/22/string-concatenation-with-java-8.html